# If $A$ and $B$ are sets of real numbers, then $(A \cup B)^{\circ} \supseteq A^ {\circ}\cup B^{\circ}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I have a proof for this question, but I want to check if I'm right and if I'm wrong, what I am missing.

Definitions you need to know to answers this question: $\epsilon$-neighborhood, interior points and interiors.  Notation: $J_{\epsilon}(a)$ means a neighborhood formed around a (i.e. $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$.  An interior point in some set $A$ is a point where an $\epsilon$-neighborhood can be formed within the set.  The set of all interior points in $A$ is denoted as $A^0$ and is called the interior.

My proof for the question:  I'm proving based on most subset proofs where you prove that if an element is in one set, then it must be in the other.  Say $x \in A^0 \cup B^0$.  Then there is a $\epsilon > 0$, where $J_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq A$ or $J_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq B$.  This implies that $J_{\epsilon}(x) \subset A \cup B$ which then implies $x \in (A \cup B)^0$.  We can conclude from here that $(A \cup B)^0 \supseteq A^0 \cup B^0$.

Comment: Proof looks fine to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is good- there is no problem with it. I have reworded a bit to make things a little more clear, specifically, where you say:

> ***Then there is $\epsilon>0$, where $J_\epsilon (x)\subseteq A$ or $J_\epsilon (x)\subseteq B$***.

Instead it would be more appropriately stated as: If $x\in A^0\cup B^0$ then $x\in A^0$ or $x\in B^0$. Then you can assume $x$ is in $A$, prove that $x\in (A\cup B)^0$, by symmetry the same argument will work if $x\in B^0$.

I have included an edited proof- but as I originally stated your proof is good,
this just more directly reflects the definitions involved.

Let $x\in A^0\cup B^0$. Then $x\in A^0$ or $x\in B^0$. Assume $x\in A^0$. Then there is, by definition, $\epsilon>0$ such that $J_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq A$. Since $A\subseteq A\cup B$, we also have $J_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq A\cup B$. Thus by definition we have $x\in (A\cup B)^0$. If instead $x\in B^0$, then by symmetry the same argument works. Thus, $A^0\cup B^0 \subseteq (A\cup B)^0$.

Comment: I agree with you that I have kind of skipped a step in my proof by assuming that one $\epsilon$ works, but I don't quite understand what's wrong with directly assuming it.  Can you explain that to me?

Comment: @Rye_yawn I had actually made a mistake and misread the original statement as $A^0\cap B^0\subseteq (A\cup B)^0$. I have edited my original answer to address this. There is just some minor things I would change- that follow more closely the definitions involved and avoid ambiguity. But your proof is good!

Comment: Thank you Curtis.  I'm self-educating myself in analysis, so any words of wisdom helps!

Comment: No problem keep it up. I definitely find when learning analysis it was useful to keep the definitions close and try and be as explicit as possible in your proofs, at least until you don't have to convince yourself something is true. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a slightly shorter proof:

We have $A^\circ \subset A \cup B$ and $B^\circ \subset A \cup B$, so we must have
$A^\circ \cup B^\circ \subset A \cup B$.

Since $A^\circ \cup B^\circ$ is open and the interior is the largest open set contained in a set, we must have
$A^\circ \cup B^\circ \subset (A \cup B)^\circ$.

Comment: Oooh!  This is nice and concise.  It's similar to the proof they have in the book I believe.  Thanks!

Comment: There is a $\cap$ which should be a $\cup$

Comment: @StefanHamcke: Thanks for catching that!