# Showing $int(A \cup B) \supseteq int(A) \cup int(B)$

Tags: general-topology

Showing $Int(A \cup B) \supseteq Int(A) \cup Int(B)$

As $A \subseteq A \cup B$ we have that $Int(A) \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$

Similarly, $Int(B) \subseteq A \cup B$

$\implies Int(A) \cup int(B) \subseteq A \cup B$

Now $Int(A) \cup Int(B)$ is an open subset of $A \cup B$. As $Int(A \cup B)$ is the union of all open subsets of $A \cup B$ we have that $Int(A) \cup Int(B) \subseteq Int(A \cup B)$

Does that look ok?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: This looks fine.  (Another way you could do this is to use $C\subseteq D \rightarrow int(C)\subseteq int(D)$.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $A$ and $B$ are sets of real numbers, then $(A \cup B)^{\circ} \supseteq A^ {\circ}\cup B^{\circ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675981/if-a-and-b-are-sets-of-real-numbers-then-a-cup-b-circ-supseteq-a)