# Counterexamples $\overset{\circ}{E} \cup \overset{\circ}{F} = \overset{\circ}{E \cup F}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I couldn't fit my question in, but I'm trying to find counter examples for $\overset{\circ}{E} \cup \overset{\circ}{E} = \overset{\circ}{E \cup F}$

My professor was talking about this in class, and I *think* she mentioned that one could find counter examples for  $\overset{\circ}{E} \cup \overset{\circ}{F} = \overset{\circ}{E \cup F}$ and $\overline{E \cap F} \subset \overline{E} \cap \overline{F}$. I'm not sure if I misheard her, but I can't come up with any counter examples where the above equality fails.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776861/a-circ-cup-b-circ-subset-a-cup-b-circ-counterexample-for-instead-of?rq=1 answer part of this question?

Comment: Hint: Sometimes $E^\circ = \emptyset$...

Comment: @QthePlatypus Thank you so much! It answers the first one.

Comment: For the second one, you wrote that you want a counterexample for $\overline{E \cap F} \subseteq \overline{E} \cap \overline{F}$. But this is the inclusion that always holds, as $\overline{E\cap F} \subseteq \overline{E}$ and $\overline{E\cap F} \subseteq \overline{F}$. It is the other inclusion that is false: take something like $E = [-1,1]\setminus \{ 0 \}$ and $F = \{ 0 \}$ on the real line.

Comment: ...and this also gives a counterexample for $(E\cup F)^\circ \subseteq E^\circ \cup F^\circ$.

Comment: @Nikitau: maybe  $A^\circ$ ans $A^-$ is a better notation. $\overline A$ is often used for the set complement.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your professor might have said:

We know that $\overline{E \cup F} = \overline{E} \cup \overline{F}$, and because $X \setminus A^{\circ} = \overline{X \setminus A}$ and $X \setminus \overline{A} = (X \setminus A)^{\circ}$ for all $A \subseteq X$, so in particular $A^{\circ} = X \setminus \overline{(X \setminus A)}$, and something similar for closure. We can express closures in interiors and vice versa using complements in $X$.

So we can use de Morgan twice to see that

\begin{multline}(E \cap F)^{\circ} = X \setminus \overline{(X \setminus (E \cap F)} = 
X \setminus \overline{(X\setminus E) \cup (X\setminus F)} = 
X \setminus (\overline{(X\setminus E)} \cup \overline{(X\setminus F)}) = \\
(X \setminus \overline{(X \setminus E)}) \cap (X \setminus \overline{(X \setminus F)}) =
 E^{\circ} \cap F^{\circ}\end{multline}

showing that the $\cup$-equality for closures gives us the $\cap$-equality for interiors.

Now we also know (presumably) that for the intersection of closures we only have $\overline{E \cap F} \subseteq \overline{E} \cap \overline{F}$, and the reverse inclusion fails in general. So there we don't have equality.

So a similar computation shows that for interiors we thus have that $(A \cup B)^{\circ} \supseteq A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$ and the reverse inclusion fails in general. And if $A,B$ form a counterexample for equality for closures (for intersection), then their complements are one for the interior equality (for unions).

A nice symmetric counterexample (where $A$ and $B$ are eqach other's complement) is $X$ the set of reals in the usual topology and $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{R \setminus Q}$, and the same example then works (by symmetry) for interior as well (both sets have empty interior and closure equal to $X$).

But working in $X = (0,2)$ we can also take $A = (0,1), B = (1,2)$ for the closures and then $A = [1,2), B = (0,1]$ works for the interiors, as expected.